# What does 'AE Recommends' imply in journal submission systems?

Tags: publications, peer-review

I have submitted my manuscript to an IEEE transaction after four months of being under review, the status has been updated to 'AE Recommends', what does this imply? Does this mean chances of acceptance are higher?